# Does the SYSVOL and NETLOGON folder need to be in the same location on all domain controllers

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller, sysvol

I recently added a new domain controller to my domain. The past admins had the SYSVOL and NETLOGON folders on the C drive. I always thought it was best practice to have them on a separate drive so when promoting the new DC to a DC, I changed the location to the  D drive.

I've run into an issue where those folders aren't replicating and users cannot log in using the new domain controller.

When I run dcdiag I get

```
 Warning: DsGetDcName returned information for \\NY1-DC01.domain.net, when we were trying to reach
     NY1-DC02.
     SERVER IS NOT RESPONDING or IS NOT CONSIDERED SUITABLE.
```

Let me know if they need to be in the same location and if so, the best way to proceed.

FYI, original DC is 2012 R2, new DC is 2016. Function level is 2012 R2

Thanks!

Comment: No, they don't need to be in the same place. Run "dcdiag /e /v" and pipe it to a text file then analyze it for errors. Check the AD and DNS related event logs on both DC's. Run the AD and DNS BPA's on both DC's.

Comment: What is each DC configured to use for DNS in the properties of the NIC?

Comment: Thanks to both of you. You helped get me in the correct direction. Turns out I wasn't thinking and forgot to check the firewall on the original DC.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was just the firewall. There's 3 hours of my life I'll never get back. I had thought that when you install AD DS it opens the correct ports but you know what happens when you assume things..

Thanks to all